# Developing iOS native app in Virtual Machine

Tags: ios, windows, virtual-machine

Is it possible to install XCode 5 and develop an iOS app on a virtual machine (running on Windows)?

**I know is not possible to upload it to the market.** I'm planning on buying a Macbook in about 2 months, but I want to start now since I don't know the language, so is it possible to do this in a virtual machine meanwhile?

PS: I heard you need mavericks OS

Comment: If you just want to learn the language, you need Xcode and a version of OSX.  Spend 2 months getting all the basics down, then get the most current version of Xcode on your Macbook when you get it.

Comment: ok i get it. I go set up a osx virtual machine and test some hello world apps with the emulator,  then when I buy the mac, i get xcode 5 and develop, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now I'm writing it from Mac OS Mavericks running on VMWare Workstation on Windows laptop. XCode works fine, i can write code and run apps on simulator and i-devices connected to USB. Last week my app created in iTunes Connect was needed to be upload (because i created it very long time ago and Apple sent me a warning letter that will remove it if I not upload build). I uploaded it without any problems (and immidiately removed it) to queit Apple. No any problems, like on MacBook :)

Comment: can i get a tutorial or similar on how to set the OS Mavericks in VMWare Workstation? or is it the common way to get mavericks.iso and install it as usual?

Comment: i downloaded special VMware-edition image from one (most) popular russian torrent tracker. I am not shure that i can give you the link to it without violation of SO rules (too lazy to read them :))
All worked at once, without needs to any setup.